# Configuring Spring transactions support for MongoDB

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data

I am using `spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb:2.2.1.RELEASE` and trying to add transaction support for Mongo DB operations.

I have the account service below, where documents are inserted into two collections `accounts` and `profiles`. In case an error occurs while inserting into `profile` collection, the insertion into `accounts` should rollback.  I have configured Spring transactions using `MongoTransactionManager`.

```
@Service
public class AccountService {

  @Transactional
  public void register(UserAccount userAccount) {
    userAccount = accountRepository.save(userAccount);
    UserProfile userProfile = new UserProfile(userAccountDoc.getId());
    userProfile = profileRepository.save(userProfile);
  }
}
```

Enabled Spring transaction support for MongoDB.

```
@Configuration
public abstract class MongoConfig extends AbstractMongoConfiguration {

  @Bean
  MongoTransactionManager transactionManager(MongoDbFactory dbFactory) {
      return new MongoTransactionManager(dbFactory);
  }
}
```

As per Spring reference doc https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/2.2.1.RELEASE/reference/html/#mongo.transactions that is all required to enable transactions for MongoDB. But this is not working. Insertions into `accounts` collection are not rolled back in case error occurs while inserting into `profiles` collection. Any suggestions if I am missing anything?

Comment: I am facing similar issue .. How did it worked for u ?

Answer (score 0):

I would use command monitoring or examine query logs on the server side to ensure that:

- session ids are sent with queries/write commands
- transaction operations are performed (there is no startTransaction command but there is a commitTransaction)